# Can we do full and incremental back ups of sharepoint site collection using powershell commands

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, administration, backup

We are using STSADM commands to use full and incremental back ups of sharepoint 2013 site collection. Planning to do using Powershell commands now but i don't see incremental and full back powershell commands online for doing site collections.

Could you help me with those commands please.

Comment: what command you are using?

Comment: The below command we are using as of now ..looking to do the same incremental back up using powershell - "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\"stsadm -o backup -url http://xyz -filename D:\SP_Backups\abc.bak -backupmethod differential -nositelock -overwrite

Comment: how many site collection in your farm? When you use the backupmethod parameter then it will not perform the site colelction level backup. i

Comment: Sorry..we are doing the back up of web application but there is only 1 site collection in the web application. Now is the above command right ?? I am looking to do same using powershell. doing incremental back up of 1 web application.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think their is any way to peform the incremental backups on the Site collections level.

> The [Backup-SPFarm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607881(v=office.14).aspx) cmdlet creates a backup for the entire farm or
>   individual components within the farm. It can also be used to back up
>   just the configuration settings of a farm to be used as a farm
>   template for other SharePoint farms. **If you want to back up a single
>   site collection, use the [Backup-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.14).aspx) cmdlet**.
>
> When the **url parameter is used**, a backup of the site collection is
>   created. However when the **backupmethod parameter** is used, a backup of
>   an individual database, Web application, or the entire farm can be
>   created. If you want to overwrite an existing backup file for a site
>   collection only, use the overwrite parameter.

Updated: You want backup of the Web application.

You can use the [backup-spfarm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607881.aspx)

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod Full -Item <WebApplicationName> [-Verbose]
```

Comment: Who did downvote, could you please explain what is the reason?